# Navbar align part right part left errors

Tags: html, css, alignment, navbar

I'm trying to create a navbar with some items on the left and some items on the right (Item 1 on the left, items 2 and 3 on the right).  My JSFiddle has my current code.

What I have tried to fix this issue:

- `float: right`
- `text-align:right`

None of them seem to work.  I'm sure there is a super simple solution, but I just can't think of it.

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
        <!--Create the button home -->
        <p class="innav">Num1</p>
        <p class="HL">|</p>
        <p class="rightIn">Num2</p>
        <p class="HL">|</p>
        <p class="rightIn">NUM 3</p>
        <p class="HL">|</p>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.navbar{
width:100%;
height: 30px;
background-color: #03572c;
}

p{
    display: inline;
}

p.innav{
color:white;
font-size: 24px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
p.rightIn{
color:white;
font-size: 24px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;

}
.HL{
margin-left: 10px;
color:white;
font-size:24px;

}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sw8dxxah/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these style to your css.

```
p.rightIn,
p:nth-child(4),
p:nth-child(6)
{
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    width: auto;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/sw8dxxah/1/)

Comment: Excellent!  When adding more childs, do I just add `p:nth-child(x)` where x is the child number?

Comment: `p:nth-child(x)` is used to float `.HL` element to the right side(the last two `.HL`). You can give custom class to them(`.HL-fl-r`). and replace with `p:nth-child(x)`

Comment: @alirezasafian I have some query on it, if we will use float to link, then link2 will be last link and link3 will be second last link how we can resolve this, I have same think need to do.
I want output like Link 1 on left side and Link 2 will be first link on right side then Link 3 will be last link of right side

Comment: You change the order of link `.link1`, `.HL`, `.HL` , `.link3`, `.HL`, `.link2`. And don't forget to change `p:nth-child(4)` and  `p:nth-child(6)` to `p:nth-child(3)` and  `p:nth-child(5)`. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/sw8dxxah/2/). There are several solutions as well.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without changing of order. This is generated dynamic can't change order of links :(

Comment: Wrap those element which you like to float right and give float right to the wrapper element. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/sw8dxxah/3/)

Comment: @Shailesh I'm sorry. I did not get you.

Comment: Thanks @alirezasafian I got solution without adding any wrapper and without any changing position of link please check this link   https://jsfiddle.net/shaileshp16/81ajq6ko/1/

Comment: @Shailesh Excellent. There are always several solutions for solving a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use a CSS grid system for this, since you are likely to need this functionality over a over on your sites.

Here are some grid systems that I have used in the past:

Pure CSS
http://purecss.io/grids/

Foundation
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Bootstrap
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Semantic UI
http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html

Or, if you feel like creating your own grid system, here is a good article about it:
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-css-grid-systems/

Comment: I think this is a comment, not an answer. Please, insert this kind of answer in the comment section.

Answer (score 2):

```css
nav {
    background: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 0;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
}
nav span {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align:right;
}
nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
    border-right:1px solid #ffffff;
}
nav a:first-child{
    float:left;
}
nav a:last-child{
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <span>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </span>
</nav>
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/shaileshp16/81ajq6ko/3/)